# PHP time for Berlin is off

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have the following PHP-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$date = date_create("2020-04-27T15:27:59+00:00", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
echo $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I expected my output to be: 2020-04-27 15:27:59 
Instead I'm getting: 2020-04-27 17:27:59 
So where are the two hours plus coming from? I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know why you are setting the timezone again before you output the date but if you remove that you get your expected result

Comment: To clarify, the `+00:00` in your time string is specifying UTC, which overrides the timezone you're passing in.

Comment: ah, okay ... now it's obvious! Thanks. My thoughts were too complicated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Berlin is 2 hours ahead from 00:00 (UTC) starting from [last Sunday of March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Germany). Since you specify 00:00 (UTC) timezone, and then convert it to Europe/Berlin, it becomes +2 hours.